# Apache wicket slider

Tags: java, javascript, apache, slider, wicket

Needless to say, I'm new to Wicket. I want to implement a slider but the examples of such seem to be rare. I found one example from wicket-stuff, a DoJo-project, but I the project doesn't compile.

Could somebody kindly share the simplest example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with wicket and sliders (using wiquery, the integration of the jquery framework into wicket) a while ago. I uploaded my playground project to github

https://github.com/magomi/pte

Please feel free to checkout the project and see if the code can help you to understand the use of sliders inside a wicket project. Simple tell me if the code is too confusing so I will provide a much simpler example how to use the slider.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I downloaded the project but unfortunately it seems a (essential) component is missing:

src\main\java\de\intecsoft\PteApplication.java:[13,44] cannot find symbol

symbol  : class SliderDemoPage
location: class de.intecsoft.PteApplication

Comment: I'm sorry. My mistake. Forgot to add the new classes before committing. Added the class right now. I double checked the content and now it should run fine. Please download it again.